# Extracting object within props

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

This is inside my `render`

```
const { thumbnail, loading, key } = this.props.video.video;
    console.log(this.props.video.video);
```

And this is my output [image]

I want to extract the thumbnails from the array of objects. But for instance if I do `this.props.video.video[0]` it returns undefined? In the end I plan on using the thumbnails to pass to another component as follows

```
videoContent = <TileFeed thumbnail={thumbnail} />;
```

Comment: what is the issue with `const { thumbnail, loading, key } = this.props.video.video;`?

Comment: this.props.video.video.video[0]. it should be. as I can see the console log

Comment: How do you get these items from an array? `const { thumbnail, loading, key } = this.props.video.video;` I mean it's a list.

Answer (score 1):

its because props may be undefined, while its being rendered,

```
    const RenderVideos = (props) => {
       if(props.videos===undefined   ){
          return <div>Loading..</div>
       }else{
          return props.videos.map((item)=> <TileFeed thumbnail={item.thumbnail} />)
       }
    }
   ...
   render(){

     return (
        <div>
            <RenderVideos videos={this.props.video.video}/>
        </div>
     )
   }
```

Comment: You can't render a list without a parent. `return this.props.video.video.map((item)=> <TileFeed thumbnail={item.thumbnail} />;)` wrap this around a `<div>` maybe

Answer (score 0):

i think you are parsing wrong array object , please map the object to see what you have? 

try this :

```
this.props.video.video.map((item)=>{
console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Add small explanation even though code is explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
class Explore extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getVideos();
  }
  render() {
    const { videos, loading, key } = this.props.videos;
    let videoContent;
    if (videos === null || loading) {
      videoContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      videoContent = <TileFeed thumbnail={videos} />;
    }
    console.log({ videoContent });

    return (
      <div className="explore">
        <div className="row">{videoContent} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Explore.propTypes = {
  getVideos: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  videos: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth,
  videos: state.videos
});
```

I had some issues with PropTypes that i'm thinking threw it off, because it is working now after configuring this